# How to change response from oracle?

Tags: ether, oracles, brownie, ganache-cli

I need to test my contract, and to test I need to change data that I recieve from ChainLink Oracle (I get Ethereum price from it). So how can I change price on ETH local for tests using Ganache-Cli or Brownie? Or how can I set my own value that Oracle will give for me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you're trying to do here is "mock" the price feed oracle's respond on your local dev network (like Ganache) etc.

You can write a mock Aggregator contract that implements [this interface](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.7/interfaces/AggregatorInterface.sol). The mock contract would "stub" (i.e. hard code) responses for method calls.

You can then deploy that mock Aggregator and inject it's address as the oracle contract in your local tests.

Note that the Chainlink Price Feeds Docs describe [how to import this interface](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/using-data-feeds#solidity)

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459287/whats-the-difference-between-a-mock-stub) for the technical difference between mocking and stubbing.